# Gulp: /usr/local/bin/gulp: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Whenever I run gulp, I get the following error:

> /usr/local/bin/gulp: No such file or directory

I've followed the answers to several related questions on SO, but none have solved my issue. I've been using gulp without issue for months, but managed to screw it up somehow.

I've removed gulp and gulp-cli (using npm) both locally and globally.

After running the following:

```
npm install -g gulp-cli
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

Any command using gulp, even `gulp -v` returns the error mentioned above. There are no errors during the installation.

I've confirmed there is nothing at `/usr/local/bin/gulp`, but **shouldn't reinstalling things recreate whatever files are supposed to be there?**

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Installing gulp globally `npm install -g gulp` doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want to install gulp locally or globally?

**Locally**

`npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-cli` should do the trick. You can then run it using:

- `./node_modules/.bin/gulp`
- `npm run gulp` if you add gulp to the scripts section of `package.json`.

**Globally**

Most likely you have a `$PATH` issue.
Did you check where your global libraries are installed by NPM?

`npm list -g`

Does installing any other global library work, or is it specific to Gulp?

*-- Edit --*

If you are using NVM, you should add the NVM setup to your rcfile (that is, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.profile` or similar). You can do so by appending these lines to your rcfile.

```sh
[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

This will load NVM and update your `PATH` so that your shell is able to find `gulp` (or any other globally-installed program by `npm` or `yarn`).

Comment: Globally, so that I can run it with just `gulp`. `npm list -g` returns hundreds of modules located at `/Users/{user}/.nvm/versions/node/v11.4.0/lib`. How would I fix a `$PATH` issue?

Comment: NVM is a game changer here. I just edited my response accordingly. It results in gulp being installed under `~/.nvm`, but the shell not being able to find it. Does running `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` on a shell fix the issue temporarily? If so, just add this line to your rcfile to make it permanent (and restart each open shell).

Comment: It did fix it temporarily. I've found a `.bash_profile` file—does that sound right? It already has something similar in it: `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"` then
`[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`. Will adding what you suggest conflict with this?

Comment: If it fixes the issue temporarily, that means that the command is not executed properly. Most likely your `.bash_profile` is not executed when opening a new terminal window -- `.bash_profile` is usually executed only for login shells. I would suggest adding these lines too `.bashrc` as well (creating it if it does not exist), or executing your `.bash_profile` from there: `source ~/.bash_profile`. Cf: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc

Comment: I created `.bashrc` with the line you suggested and everything seems to be working as expected. Really appreciate your help! You're a lifesaver.

Comment: Executing `./node_modules/.bin/gulp` locally does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Try `npx gulp` so that npm using the gulp version that is installed in your dependencies.

Comment: `npx gulp -v` works, and returns `CLI version 2.0.1` and `Local version 4.0.0`. How can I fix it so I don't have to use `npx`?