# `gulp` command doesn't work as expected on Linux

Tags: linux, gulp

I am trying to set up the needed environment for a project I am gonna work on. I am not able to run `gulp` command as expected (as it is told on the  [getting started](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start) page of Gulp).
I am using Linux (PopOS) which is based on Ubuntu and Debian.

So, I have tried to fix it in the local project repo - which was unsuccessful.

Then I decided to create a new project directory and see whether it works. I have done these in the new project file:

```
$ node -v
v8.10.0

$ npm -v
5.6.0

$ npx -v
9.7.1

$ npm install --global gulp-cli
$ npm install --save-dev gulp
```

After all these, at the last step, when I do:

```
$ gulp
-bash: /usr/bin/gulp: No such file or directory
```

this is what I get.

However, if I do this,

```
$ node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --version
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

I get some result.

Does anybody see why `gulp` isn't getting in my binary directory? - Even though I have done the same exact steps that are presented on the official website?

Comment: Might your problem be addressed here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54986239/gulp-usr-local-bin-gulp-no-such-file-or-directory?rq=1` ?

Comment: What does `ldd /usr/bin/gulp` say?

Comment: Does `gulp -v` do anything?

Comment: `ldd /usr/bin/gulp` gives `No such file or directory` @Roadowl
`gulp -v` says Command `gulp` not found. @Mark
The problem is, `gulp-cli` is not being installed globally somehow.

Comment: @Roadowl thanks for the reference to the other question. It is actually the same problem but I am using Linux as OS, so I thought my problem might be related to something else.
`npx gulp` (which is mentioned in that question) works for me too, but the reason why I should use `npx` and cannot simply run the command `gulp` after doing the steps on official site is remaining unknown.

Comment: I cannot square `-bash: /usr/bin/gulp: No such file or directory`, where somehow a complete path is given, with `ldd /usr/bin/gulp  No such file or directory`.

Comment: What do `type gulp` and `ls -la /usr/bin/gulp` say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was about npm prefix that defines the directory where npm packages will be installed. Because the gulp binary wasn't in one of the directories that is in `PATH` variable bash wasn't able to find it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090835/npm-install-not-installing-things-at-usr-bin) you can find details about how to fix.